# How to set up Facebook webhook to monitor a particular page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks

I've been searching the net on how to setup the Facebook webhooks to check a particular Facebook page (I'm a content editor of) for certain updates.

I read the docs many times about setting up the callback URL whenever a particular "event" happens on that Facebook page, but I never read a straight answer on how to tell which page I want to monitor in.

I was pointed to the `{app-id}/subscriptions` endpoint, but it doesn't seem to be the one I need.

Could someone provide an idea on how this works?

Answer (score 15):

You need to make a request to [`/{page_id}/subscribed_apps`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/#Creating) to create a subscription for updates from a page.

This call needs a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens), so you need to request `manage_pages` permission first from an admin of the page. (Not sure if “content editor” role is sufficient for that.)

Comment: This question has some code examples on how to subscribe and unsubscribe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36443766/how-to-unsubscribe-an-app-from-a-page-for-facebook-webhook-lead-ad